# Word for "Made friends with"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently working on a college essay with a 350 max word count. I want the essay to be precise, dense, and meaningful. Is there an elegant replacement for "I became friends with"?

Comment: We don't normally give writing advice here, but remember there is a verb "befriended". Look it up.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help], as well as the guidance for making [tag:single-word-requests], for a better understanding of the kinds of questions we can entertain here.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is **befriend**. It is a transitive verb with the definition:

> to become or act as a friend to
>   - *befriended the new student*
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/befriend)</sub>